# Extendible hashing - most significant bits

Tags: python, algorithm, hash

I want to write extendible hashing. On [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extendible_hashing) I have found good implementation in python. But this code uses least significant bits, so when I have hash `1101` for `d = 1` value is `1` and for `d = 2` value is `01`. I would like to use most significant bits. For exmaple: hash `1101`, `d = 1` value is `1`, `d = 2` value is `11`. Is there any simple way to do that? I tried, but I can't.

> Do you understand why it uses the least significant bits?

More or less. It makes efficient when we using arrays. Ok so for hash function I would like to use four least bits from 4-bytes integer but from left to right.

```
h = hash(k) 
h = h & 0xf #use mask to get four least bits
p = self.pp[ h >> ( 4 - GD)]
```

And it doesn't work, and I don't know why.

Comment: You say you have tried - post the code so we can see where you have gone wrong.

Comment: Do you understand *why* it uses the least significant bits?

Comment: When you say you want the most significant bits, do you want to limit that to a specific size of integer, or to the top non-zero bits? For instance, are the most significant four bits of the 8-bit number 15 (aka `00001111`) `0000` or `1111`? The former is easy to calculate, the latter less so (it probably requires a `log`).

Comment: What does "but from left to right" and "least bits" mean? What is `GD`? And why do you care about using some four bits over any other four bits? If your hash function is any good, it is effectively a random number, and no matter which four bits you choose, it's still a random number.

Answer (score 2):

Computing a hash using the least significant bits is the fastest way to compute a hash, because it only requires an AND bitwise operation. This makes it very popular.

Here is an implemetation (in C) for a hash using the most significant bits. Since there is no direct way to know the most significant bit, it repeatedly tests that the remaining value has only the specified amount of bits.

```
int significantHash(int value, int bits) {
    int mask = (1 << bits) - 1;
    while (value > mask) {
        value >>= 1;
    }
    return value;
}
```

I recommend the overlapping hash, that makes use of all the bits of the number. Essentially, it cuts the number in parts of equal number of bits and XORs them. It runs slower than the least significant hash, but faster than the significant hash. Above all else, it offers a better dispersion than the other two methods, making it a better candidate when the numbers that must be hashed have a certain bit-related-pattern.

```
int overlappingHash(int value, int bits) {
    int mask = (1 << bits) - 1;
    int answer = 0;
    do {
        answer ^= (value & mask);
        value >>= bits;
    } while (value > 0);
    return answer;
}
```